# Fetch the Attribute Value from the XML file

Tags: ansible

I want to read the attribute value based upon the attribute name from the following xml file using ansible:

```
XML:
<results
    xmlns="urn:www-collation-com:1.0">
    <ComputerSystem array="1" guid="qwertyuioasjklzxcvbnm"/>
</results>
```

Able to fetch the values from the property names and values, but not able to fetch the attribute value based upon the attribute names.

Expected output:

> guid="qwertyuioasjklzxcvbnm"

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Read an attribute values
      xml:
        path: /root/foo.xml
        xpath: /results/ComputerSystem
        content: text
      register: xmlresp

    - name: Show an attribute value
      debug:
        var: xmlresp.matches
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output, use this expression:

```
//*[local-name()='ComputerSystem']/@guid
```

It ignores the namespaces and its output is

> qwertyuioasjklzxcvbnm

Comment: Expression you mentioned were not related to ansible, i am working on ansible xml parsing

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: Getting error. "msg": "Xpath //*[local-name()='ComputerSystem']/@guid does not reference a node!"   ```                                                                                       - name: Read an element's attribute values
      xml:
        path: /root/foo.xml
        xpath: //*[local-name()='ComputerSystem']/@guid
        content: text
      register: xmlresp```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested.
For namespace there is a different setting to be given

```
  - name: test xml
    xml:
       path: /tmp/foo.xml
       xpath: /x:results
       namespaces:
        x: urn:www-collation-com:1.0
       attribute: ComputerSystem
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html